# DualShock 4 seems to hijack/autoswitch Unity Input System over bluetooth - how can I prevent this?

Tags: unity-game-engine, input

I have recently been learning Unity and have chosen to use the "new" input system. It seems very powerful and I'm keen to use it, however using a DualShock 4 controller seems to brute force its way to the front every few frames - perhaps every 250-500ms at most.

I have set up a control scheme [thus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHYhj.png)

I then reference this basically as the Unity docs outline:

```
public InputActionAsset actions;
private InputAction moveAction;
private InputAction fireAction;

void Awake()
{
    moveAction = actions.FindActionMap("ShipFlight").FindAction("Move");
    fireAction = actions.FindActionMap("ShipFlight").FindAction("Fire");
}

void Update()
{
    var moveVector = moveAction.ReadValue<Vector2>();

    //Debugs to log moveAction.activeControl and moveVector

    //Very basic transform.localPosition stuff
    ApplyMovement(moveVector);
}

//OnEnable and OnDisable
```

So...the values of moveAction.activeControl...

**With no controller connected (bluetooth pairing removed):**

Initial: Null
Upon touching WASD/Arrows: Key:/Keyboard/correspondingKey

**With no DS4 connected (but with the DS4 bluetooth pairing added):**

Initial: Stick/DualShock4GamepadHID/leftStick
Upon touching WASD/Arrows: Key:/Keyboard/correspondingKey

This value sticks around.

**With bluetooth paired but not powered on, old wired X360 controller connected:**

Initial: Null
Upon touching X360 LS: Stick:/XInputControllerWindows/leftStick
Upon touching WASD/Arrows: Key:/Keyboard/correspondingKey

Touching either control will "snap" the logged activeControl to that source.

**With DS4 connected:**

Initial: Stick/DualShock4GamepadHID/leftStick
Upon touching WASD/Arrows: Key:/Keyboard/correspondingKey
Almost immediately after (not even letting go of the key): Stick/DualShock4GamepadHID

Using DS4 works as expected, but trying to use WASD or Arrows results in input immediately halting and swapping to DS4 input, interrupting whatever was being received from the keyboard.

"Almost immediately" seems to be anything from a frame or two, to a handful of frames, which made me wonder if there's a fixed update from the controller which grabs focus and forcefully swaps the active device. I've tried this with two different DS4s. For kicks, I also checked X360 controller input, and the DS4 steamrollers *that* as well.

I suppose I could probably add "AnalogMove" as a completely separate vector which is only processed if the values are non-zero, but that seems to defeat the purpose of using the input system. Has anyone seen this behaviour before? Is it a known issue? I can't find any recent mentions of the issue anywhere. Does anyone know how I might circumvent/solve this issue?